# composer: RuntimeException

Tags: git, composer-php, neoscms

I am trying to install Typo3-Neos via the composer.

I follow the listed instructions:

- `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
  to download the composer
- `php composer.phar self-update`
  already up to date
- `php composer.phar create-project -s beta typo3/neos-base-distribution Neos-2.0`
  try to download Typo3-Neos

During the last step following message shows up:

```
# php composer.phar create-project -s beta typo3/neos base-distribution Neos-2.0
Installing typo3/neos-base-distribution (2.0.0-beta2)
 - Installing typo3/neos-base-distribution (2.0.0-beta2)
   Cloning f344c0bdc9b2f83341f443c66d460204eaa0afd2

Created project in Neos-2.0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing composer/installers (v1.0.21)
   Loading from cache

Class TYPO3\Flow\Composer\InstallerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-package-install script
 - Installing symfony/console (v2.7.0)
   Loading from cache

Class TYPO3\Flow\Composer\InstallerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-package-install script
 - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.5.12)
   Loading from cache

Class TYPO3\Flow\Composer\InstallerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-package-install script
 - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.5.12)
   Loading from cache

... a few more

Class TYPO3\Flow\Composer\InstallerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-package-install script
  - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.4.7)
Loading from cache

Class TYPO3\Flow\Composer\InstallerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-package-install script
  - Installing typo3/eel (3.0.0-beta3)
    Cloning 108cd4e87cbdfb1d797a513590a3a77466248f8f

[RuntimeException]

  Failed to execute git checkout
 '108cd4e87cbdfb1d797a513590a3a77466248f8f' --   
  && git reset --hard
 '108cd4e87cbdfb1d797a513590a3a77466248f8f'     --              
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): 
 .git
```

In one blog entry the author described to update the git version of the machine. I tried that to. The current git version is (gentoo linux - listed with used use flags):

```
 dev-vcs/git-2.4.1::gentoo  USE="blksha1 cgi curl gpg iconv nls  
 pcre perl python threads webdav -cvs -doc -emacs -gnome-keyring 
 -gtk -highlight -mediawiki (-ppcsha1) -subversion {-test} -tk 
 -xinetd" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 0 KiB
```

What can be the reason for the RuntimeException? An error inside composer, neos or due to local configuration (php,git,...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/996 mentions a workaround.

```
composer update --prefer-dist
```

did the work

Answer (score 0):

`sudo composer update` fixed my issue, probably because at some point you ran a composer update in sudo mode

Comment: This answer is really similar to the already accepted 4 years old one. Could you consider adding a comment to that one asking to improve it?

Comment: This is probably sufficiently different, as it implies calling `composer` under `sudo` produces a different result